# Adding a sqlalchemy reconstructor method with a class decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a mapped class with a @reconstructor method that creates a lookup dictionary from a relationship with this class. **This works.** It's called in the init (explicitly), then is also called by sqlalchemy on reconstruction from the database and maps each instance's related 'compounds' to self.compound, such that self.compound['compound_name'] retrieves the compound with that name from the related field, self.compounds. It functions in ~constant time, as opposed to the previous linear searching of self.compounds that I had. That's great...

```
@reconstructor
def _create_lookup(self):
    print('Create lookup called.')
    attr = getattr(self, 'compounds')

    lookup = dict(zip(
        [getattr(c, 'name') for c in attr],
        [getattr(c, '', c) for c in attr]
    ))

    setattr(self, 'compound', lookup)
```

**However**, the more general form below does not work when used as a class decorator (I want this because this behavior is desirable for several of my classes, but wouldn't necessarily inherit well):

```
def give_class_lookup_on_attr(attr_to_lookup, lookup_key_attr, lookup_value_attr, lookup_name):

    # None is a key for the lookup_value_attr to return the object itself (set in the default)
    if lookup_value_attr is None:
        lookup_value_attr = ''
        # passing an empty string will never find an attribute, which makes it the key for returning the default

    print('give_class_... decorator called.')

    def class_wrap(cls):

        @reconstructor
        def func(self):
            print('Create lookup called.')
            attr = getattr(self, attr_to_lookup)

            lookup = dict(zip(
                [getattr(c, lookup_key_attr) for c in attr],
                [getattr(c, lookup_value_attr, c) for c in attr]
                # return the object as the value in dict if attr is not present
            ))

            setattr(self, lookup_name, lookup)

        cls._create_lookup = func
        print('reconstructor method added to cls and cls returned')
        return cls

    return class_wrap
```

Per the print statements, I've been able to confirm that when I call my decorator on my class with the appropriate parameters, the reconstructor is created on the class, but is never called. I've also checked the class method's .__sa_reconstructor__ flag, which is set to True (the only thing the reconstructor decorator does to a method). But, it **still is not called.**

Because the decorator on the class is called after the class is made, and then the class is passed in, my working assumption is that sqlalchemy's mapper has already done it's work (which is why this works when done in-line to the class, but not with the class decorator), so it never finds the decorator-added reconstructor method.

So, is my assumption on the right track, and are there any ways of refreshing sqlalchemy's mapper to have it take a second look post-decoration? Or, should I start looking at writing and/or adding my own sqlalchemy event listeners (assuming they won't have the same issue).

EDIT:
My assumption *seems* further confirmed by:

```
mapper = class_mapper(MyMappedClass)  
print(mapper._reconstructor)
```

If I call the above in my tests with my in-line method declaration, it returns the reconstructor (function MyMappedClass._create_lookup at 0x7f452a49e8c8), but returns None when using my class decorator.

Comment: The decorator is just convenience over the event system: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.InstanceEvents.load

Comment: Thanks @IljaEverilä I was hoping to avoid that, but it was actually quite simple to implement for the load event. I'm now a bit stuck on having the method I'm adding (cls._create_lookup) get called  _after_ the \__init__ is called, which the 'init' event explicitly does not do, per the docs. Is there any common pattern for this?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will save someone else the trouble. My answer is part-Python, and part-Sqlalchemy thanks to @IljaEverilä.

It's extremely similar to my first version, but uses the 'load' event from sqlalchemy to handle being re-loaded from the database, and otherwise will only create it's lookup dictionary if it's called and isn't available (via a property).

The property may be replaced with the 'init' event from sqlalchemy, but only if whatever it references is available (or not accessed) *prior* to the init being run. In my case, accessing relationships before the __init__ is called always resulted in empty lookup tables.

```
def give_class_lookup_on_attr(attr_to_lookup, lookup_key_attr, lookup_value_attr, lookup_name):
    # None is a key for the lookup_value_attr to return the object itself (set in the default)
    if lookup_value_attr is None:
        lookup_value_attr = ''
        # passing an empty string will never find an attribute, which makes it the key for returning the default

    def class_wrap(cls):

        def func(self):
            attr = getattr(self, attr_to_lookup)

            lookup = dict(zip(
                [getattr(c, lookup_key_attr) for c in attr],
                [getattr(c, lookup_value_attr, c) for c in attr]
            ))

            # set a private attr as "self._<lookup_name>"
            setattr(self, '_' + lookup_name, lookup)

        cls._create_lookup = func

        # create a property getter to reveal private attr, bind lookup_name to it
        def prop_getter(self, name=lookup_name):
            attr = getattr(self, '_' + name, None)

            if not attr:
                print('Lookup was not found. Created and returned.')
                self._create_lookup()
                attr = getattr(self, '_' + name)

            return attr

        setattr(cls, lookup_name, property(prop_getter))

        @event.listens_for(cls, 'load')
        def recieve_load(target, context):
            target._create_lookup()

        return cls

    return class_wrap
```